# determine Big-Oh / Big-Theta or Big-Omega

Tags: complexity-theory

Given f(n) = n^[(1+sin(n*pi/2))/2]  and g(n) = n^0.5
, how do I prove that f(n) = O(g(n)) / f(n) = Omega(g(n)) / f(n) = Theta(g(n)).

I have worked out that f(n) doesn't seem to have a bound as the function grows bigger and smaller as n grows big.... (i plotted the graph here)
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/xtrh124rjb

So How would one justify which does it belong to ?
Or does it belong to neither of them since it doesn't have a bound at all....?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence 1, 5, 9, …, 4k + 1, … For these values of n, (1 + sin(n * pi / 2)) / 2 = 1. Therefore, for these values of n, your function is identical to the function A(n) = n^1 = n. Note that A(n) = n is NOT O(g(n)) = O(n^0.5); n grows asymptotically faster than n^0.5.

Consider the sequence 3, 7, 11, …, 4k + 3, … For these values of n, (1 + sin(n * pi / 2)) / 2 = 0. Therefore, for these values of n, your function is identical to the function B(N) = n^0 = 1. Note that B(n) = 1 is NOT Omega(g(n)) = Omega(n^0.5); n^0.5 grows asymptotically faster than the constant 1 (which doesn't grow at all).

Either f(n) not being O(g(n)) OR f(n) not being Omega(g(n)) would have already disqualified f(n) from being Theta(g(n)).

Note: f(n) = O(A(n)) and f(n) = O(B(n)). f(n) = Theta(h(n)) where h(n) is any function which oscillates like f(n) and which grows at least as fast and which has a constant lower bound.